# C# generic processors

Tags: c#, generics

I have a problem which takes a standard combination of inputs, however there are a several algorithms ('processors') which can solve it.  The output is a Boolean.  Each processor is only valid for one particular scenario, and there will never be more than one processor which is valid.

Each processor determines whether it is valid or not by having some initial inputs supplied to it.  If it is valid, then it calculates some information based on those initial inputs, and stores it - since that information is useful in the final process.  Then, if it is valid, then additional inputs are supplied to the processor and it returns an output.

If no processor is valid then a default answer is given.

So the algorithm is like this in pseudo code:

```
process(inputs) 
   for each processor
      determine validity and get data
      if valid
         use data to output result
      end if
   end for
  output default result
end
```

Here is a C# example, which isn't syntactically valid. And its just an example, in real life the inputs are more complex than strings and integers.  The computation of the second input (int i in the contrived example) is executed repeatedly inside a loop, whereas the first input is only calculated once - hence the separation of whether a process if valid from what the result of the processor is.  As an alternative to using an IEnumerable, we could have an array or list of processors.

```
   public class ProcessController
   {
      public static IEnumerable<Processor<X>> GetProcessors<X>() where X: ProcessorInfo
      {
         yield return new ProcessorA();
         yield return new ProcessorB();
      }

      public static bool Process<X>(String s, int i) where X : ProcessorInfo
      {
         foreach (Processor<X> processor in GetProcessors<X>())
         {
            X x = (X) processor.GetInfoIfCanProcess(s);
            if (x != null)
            {
               return processor.GetResult(x, i);
            }
         }
         return false;
      }
   }

   public abstract class Processor<T> where T: ProcessorInfo
   {
      public abstract T GetInfoIfCanProcess(String s);

      public abstract bool GetResult(T info, int i);
   }

   public interface ProcessorInfo
   {
      bool IsValid();
   }

   public class ProcessorA: Processor<ProcessorA.ProcessorInfoA>
   {
      public class ProcessorInfoA: ProcessorInfo
      {
         public bool IsValid()
         {
            //do something!
         }
      }

      public override ProcessorInfoA GetInfoIfCanProcess(string s)
      {
         //do something!
      }

      public override bool GetResult(ProcessorInfoA info, int i)
      {
         //do something!
      }
   }

   public class ProcessorB : Processor<ProcessorB.ProcessorInfoB>
   {
      public class ProcessorInfoB : ProcessorInfo
      {
         public bool IsValid()
         {
            //do something!
         }
      }

      public override ProcessorInfoB GetInfoIfCanProcess(string s)
      {
         //do something!
      }

      public override bool GetResult(ProcessorInfoB info, int i)
      {
         //do something!
      }
   }
```

I am getting syntax errors in the GetProcessors method: Cannot implicitly convert type `Play.ProcessorA` to `Play.Processor<X>`.  How can I get around this?

Comment: I don't think most of the question was necessary. The question is really about generics syntax but adding all of the additional info about your algorithm and the pseudo code is just adding noise in my opinion.

Comment: you could return `IEnumerable<ProcessorInfo>` to get around this problem

Comment: Why doesn't your `Processor<T>` class use `T` anywhere in its definition?

Comment: Ah, the ol' covariance/contravariance problem.

Comment: The generics were not implemented correctly in my minimum working example, I have corrected it now.  Each processor can only accept a ProcessorInfo of its own type into the GetResult method.  The ProcessorInfo classes will all have a different structure, and since they are all different it can be an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to couple a processor class and its processor info class using generics, which is problematic. You end up with a loose couping where you just cast the objects to what they should be, instead of making the generics assure that the types are correct.

I suggest that you avoid that problem by storing the info in the class itself. The code that runs the processor doesn't have to know anything about the information that the processor uses, it only has to know if the processor is valid or not.

Return a boolean instead of a ProcessorInfo object, and keep the relevant data in the Processor object. If the processor is valid, it has the data that it needs. If not, it will go away along with the data that it got from the first step when you go on to try the next processor.

Comment: I did think of this but the reason why I didn't do it this way is that I dislike any sort of pattern where you can't call one method on an object until you have called another method. The GetResult method would not be meaningful until you had called the IsValid method.  I would probably keep an internal flag within the classifier which would have three states - valid, invalid and not known.  If GetResult is called when the validity is not known, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to fix this is using `OfType`:

```
private static IEnumerable<object> GetProcessors()
{
    yield return new ProcessorA();
    yield return new ProcessorB();
}

public static IEnumerable<Processor<X>> GetProcessors<X>() where X: ProcessorInfo
{
    return GetProcessors.OfType<Processor<X>>();
}
```

Since `Processor<X>` is invariant there is no common type you can use, and since `X` is chosen outside the method you need to use a dynamic type check.

Comment: That's great, thanks!  And you can also do:

`private static readonly object[] arr = { new ProcessorA(), new ProcessorB() };

public static IEnumerable<Processor<X>> GetProcessors<X>() where X : ProcessorInfo
{
   return arr.OfType<Processor<X>>();
}`

Comment: I can't get it to work.  If you do `OfType<Processor<X>>()` it returns an enumerable with nothing in it, if you try and cast the array or its individual elements you get an InvalidCastException.  I think I am going to have to go with @Guffa's answer, which is a shame :(.

Comment: @PaulRichards - This should work but be aware that your `Processor<X>` class is invariant. If you call `GetProcessors<ProcessorA.ProcessorInfoA>()` you will get an instance of `ProcessorA`, however if you call `GetProcessors<ProcessorInfo>` you will not get any matches since neither `ProcessorA` nor `ProcessorB` is not an instance of `Processor<ProcessorInfo>` due to invariance.

Comment: you can't do `GetProcessors<ProcessorA.ProcessorInfoA>()` though because the point of doing it is to have one process method that runs through all the processors.

Comment: @PaulRichards - In your code, `Process<X>` calls `GetProcessors<X>` so  the caller of that method must know the exact type to use.

Comment: I put the '<x>' in just to get it to compile; the calling code doesn't know which type to use.  Each type implements the 'IsValid' method.  The calling code needs to iterate through ALL the processors, it doesn't know which one is valid until 'IsValid' returns true.